# Version increment when we have both bug fixes and minor imporvments

Tags: versioning

I have a pattern for versioning my program:

```
major.minor.patch
```

*Major* is a complete new version of the program which is seldom increased. *Minor* is for new features and *patch* for bug fixes.

The question is, if in a new update of my program I have a new feature and I have also fixed a few bugs, should *patch* and *minor* both be incremented or does an increase of minor would suffice while patch remains zero?

Comment: I think this is a totally personal decision, but I suggest incrementing both to stick with your versioning system. To be clear: If your version is 0.1.3 make it 0.2.1

Comment: @purplehuman if my current version is `1.0.0`, do you suggest my next version that has both  minor and path increased be `1.1.1` or `1.1.0`?

Comment: I'd say 1.1.1, 0.1 for improvements, 0.0.1 for new fixes. But it's a personal choice of course. I'd just do it this way.

Comment: I'm using a similar versioning system, and this is what I do.

Answer (score 2):

As @purplehuman pointed it out, it is rather a personal decision and has no big consequence.

The convention I guess would be to increment the minor (to 1.1.x), and set the patch level to 0 because a patch level is usually relative to a version (major.minor). I would add that it may be odd to some people to switch from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1 without going through the 1.1.0.

But it is not *that* important, IMHO. Usually bug fixes may come in any major or minor new release, so the users would probably go check the changelog to see if/what bug fixes have be made. So don't spend too much time on this. ;-)